# Sqlite - insert into multiple tables with an auto-increment PID

Tags: sqlite

I'm using SQLite. I have two tables:

```
Log:
    pid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
    action INTEGER NOT NULL
    .... ect.

ErrorExtras:
    pid INTEGER REFERENCES log(pid)
    msg TEXT,
    request TEXT
```

Now when an error occurs, I want to insert into both. Inserting into Log is easy, as it generates the PID, however, inserting into ErrorExtras is harder since I don't know the PID without doing a query. If I insert into Log, query for the PID and then insert into ErrorExtras, that seems quie messy. Is there some kind of shortcut for these kinds of inserts?

In my case, this is possible because the other info in log uniquely identifies the pid (so there's a combined key), but what if this weren't the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needn't query for the insert_id, just use the [last_insert_id](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html) in the select statement in `ErrorExtras` and Bob's your uncle.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control of your SQL commands, you can use the [`last_insert_rowid` SQL function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid) like this:

```
INSERT INTO Log(action) VALUES(42);
INSERT INTO ErrorExtras(pid, msg) VALUES(last_insert_rowid(), 'x');
```

(But this works only for the very next `INSERT` command, because afterwards, `last_insert_rowid()` returns the `rowid` of the `ErrorExtras` record.)

---

If you are using the C API, you can use the [`sqlite3_last_insert_rowid` function](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html):

```c
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "INSERT INTO Log(action) VALUES(42)", -1, &stmt, NULL);
sqlite3_step(stmt);
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "INSERT INTO ErrorExtras(pid,msg) VALUES(?,?)", -1, &stmt, NULL);
sqlite3_bind_int64(stmt, 1, sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(db));
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, "x", -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_step(stmt);
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

---

The APIs of other languages typically also have some mechanism to get the last inserted `rowid`.
For example, in Android, the `insert` function returns it:

```java
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("action", 42);
long log_rowid = db.insert("Log", null, cv);
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("pid", log_rowid);
cv.put("msg", "x");
db.insert("ErrorExtras", null, cv);
```